# How to intercept requests in JSON Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to integrate [JSON server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) with a test project that I'm working on, but one of my JS libraries, which handles the Ajax requests, formats the data in a particular way before submitting that I do not want. Is there an easy way in JSON server to intercept the incoming and outgoing requests to change the data a bit?

In the actual project, this logic will have to be at the level of the controller, but I'm far from implementing that for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer to my question was in the README that I hadn't read well enough. You need to use the `router.render()` option to modify the requests and the responses to your liking.